# Share text,images in wordpress api android

Tags: android, wordpress, android-sharing

How to do wordpress sharing in android application without Using Native App Of Wordpress?

Comment: @Aღmirkhan: thanks, sorry for my poor english.

Comment: No problem, Edit is just for maintaining site quality, Welcome to stack overflow